# Send mail using java code is working with few network and not working with few?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have tried lot of method to solve the issue . I have used 3 ports (25,465,587) all are not working with few network . Error Message is

> "java.mail.MessageingException:Could not connect to SMTP host:
>   smtp.gmail.com,port:587; nested exception is :
>   java.net.ConnectException:failed to connect to
>   smtp.gmail.com/2404:6800:4008:c00::6d(port 587) after 90000ms : is
>   Connected failed : ENETUNREACH(Network is Unreachable)"

```
  Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);
  MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 
  msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 
  InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
  for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
    addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
  } 
    msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
  msg.setSubject(_subject); 
  msg.setSentDate(new Date());
  BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
  messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
  _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
  msg.setContent(_multipart);
  Transport.send(msg);     
props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 
props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Comment: Have you tried to do a simple command line telnet call to your target addresses to see that they are *really* valid?

Comment: 'Network not reachable' is a firewall problem on your side, or, as you seem to be trying IPv6, a DNS problem.

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has [connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).